# Pull a commit into another branch exactly (without merging)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I have a structure similar to below:

```
C1 -- C2  --  C3
               \ -- C4
```

I want to pull `C3` on back on top of `C4`.  (*NB:  `C3` & `C3a` hold the save files*)

```
C1 -- C2  --  C3
               \ -- C4 -- C3a
```

If I try to merge or pull I am just told I am already up to date.

How can I force a 're-merge' so that I can get `C3` back on top?

Comment: What was your workflow? What happens to `C2`?

Comment: @Cratylus My bad diagramming, `C2` should have bee on the other branch as well.

Comment: Your diagram is confusing: two of your commits bear the same label (`C3`).

Comment: @Jubobs You're right (too much time using TFS).  I'll improve it.  Is that better?

Comment: @BanksySan I'm still confused, though. What does `C3a` represent/contain? Do you not simply want to swap `C3` and `C4` and obtain `C1 -- C2 -- C4 -- C3`?

Comment: On one branch, yes, `C3a`, should contain exactly the same files as `C3`.  I imagine it'll have a difference commit ID though.  That's why I called them `C3` and `C3a`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to revert C4, so that the branch returns to what it looks like before you did C4. If you haven't yet pushed, you can just move your branch pointer back to C3. If you've already pushed, you can git-revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current branch, I don't think you can do that since C3 is already merged in the branch.

You can try cherry-picking commits on a new branch though, which should give desired results:

1. First, create new branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b new_branch <C1>
   ```
2. Now cherry pick C4 on this new_branch:

   ```
   git cherry-pick C4
   ```
3. Now cherry pick C# on the new_branch:

   ```
   git cherry-pick C3
   ```

The above should give the desired results in the `new_branch`:

```
C1 -- C2  --  C3
  \-- C4  -- C3
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understand you correctly, you can use [git cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to move your `C3` commit on the top of `C4`